# Shaders file fail compilefromfile

Tags: c++, visual-studio, shader, directx-11, vertex-shader

When i do D3DX11CompileFromFile it fail for some reason.

I added shaders.shader file to project folder and into project
http://prntscr.com/9gq92f

Allso here is code from shader file

```
struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    VOut output;

    output.position = position;
    output.color = color;

    return output;
}

float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post errors log? Also How I know input params os pixel shader should be the same as output param vertex shader. Try this: float4 PShader(VOut vOut) : SV_TARGET

Comment: There is no error log. I set statement if (FAILED...) and then with debuger i see if it fail or not.

Comment: DirectX will output compilation errors to output. For Example: In Visual Studio output.

Comment: You need to provide the code snippet for the actual call to ``D3DX11CompileFromFile`` to determine the reason for the error. Note that D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 are [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). You can call ``D3DCompileFromFile`` directly instead of using this old wrapper function. See [HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx)